# Table with images - align text to image

Tags: tables, graphics, align, tabularx

I am trying to include images in a table. It is working fine so far, but I want the top of the image to align with the text. Right now the image is 'too high' in relation to the text. Is there an easy way to fix this? Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp] 
    \centering
    \caption[caption I]{caption text\label{tab:labeltext}}
\begin{footnotesize}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{9em}>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{11em}}
        
    \toprule
    picture & text1 &  text 2 & text3 \\
    \midrule

    \includegraphics[height=.8cm]{example-image-a}& \blindtext  & \blindtext & \blindtext \\%\addlinespace
    \includegraphics[height=.8cm]{example-image-a}& text  & text & text \\
    
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{footnotesize}  
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` to the preamble and using `\includegraphics[height=.8cm, valign=t]{example-image-a}` should work.

Comment: Thank, this is working